# Comparing two versions of a Wiki Pages will not highlight the text added

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, publishing-site

I tried to compare two versions of a Wiki article ; but I have noticed that if there is a text added to a new version, it will not be visible to the user unless he move the cursor over it (where it will only show a small tool tip).

so is there a way to change the colour of the added text.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have updated the COREV15 file to change the color of the added & deleted text